# cakephp saving into tables that has actas => requester for another model

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, actas

i have a crm that has many customers,groups,users,products,departments etc. The  form for each will is different (depending on the customers specifications). So baking different view for each form was not possible, so i created a set of controller models and views through which i can create forms dynamically (like rs forms in joomla). these controller will get the form dynamically and when the form is submitted it will import the model to which the data must be saved and then insert it within the form controller , edit also had the same logic.I was able to create that and insert data into different tables . The issue is when i try to insert into tables like users and groups i get an error. The reason is there is a actas=>requestor present in both table.

everything works fine if i try to insert user or groups from their respective controller. But it does not works when i import the users or groups(the model that has actas>requestor) to forms and then try inserting.

if i try to remove actas=>requestor then the form insert to users and groups properly but aro will not get populated.

any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: It would help if you showed what error is displayed

Comment: i finally got it...well 
app::import is not the best method to do a thing like what i have, instead of using app:import  i tried using this

ClassRegistry::init("modelname");

http://api.cakephp.org/class/class-registry#method-ClassRegistryinit

its working now and the aros are builing properly

Answer (score 0):

i finally got it...well

```
app::import
```

is not the best method to do a thing like what i have, instead of using app:import i tried using this

```
eClassRegistry::init("modelname");
```

api.cakephp.org/class/class-registry#method-ClassRegistryinit

its working now and the aros are builing properly